# Excel VBA script to concatenate two cell contents into one

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Concat()

   Do While ActiveCell <> "" 

      'The rows are filtered to display only "London"
      'The changes required are for "London" only

      If ActiveCell.Offset(0,0) = "London" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1 = _
           ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = ""
      End If
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   Loop

End Sub
```

I have close to 13500 rows.
This doesn't work. I can't see any noticeable changes made.

Comment: I haven't written any. I don't know where to begin. or how.

Comment: I tried this - Sub ConcatColumns()

   Do While ActiveCell <> ""  'Loops until the active cell is blank.

      'The "&" must have a space on both sides or it will be
      'treated as a variable type of long integer.

      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)

      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   Loop

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Concat()

   Do While ActiveCell <> "" 

      With ActiveCell
         If .Value = "London" Then
             .Value = .Value & .Offset(0, 1).Value
             .Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
         End If
      End With

      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, this is throwing a "loop without do" error. Despite removing the extra End If in your code.

Comment: @Selvam can you try it again?

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Further on the same, when the rows are collapsed by filter, without the use of a VBA script, can I fill all the revealed rows with a "value", without changing the contents of the hidden rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a loop using a `for each` statement to loop through all the rows in the worksheet's UsedRange. For each row, check to see if the value in the first column of the row is "London" and if so overwrite the contents of the column with the combination of column1 & column2.

Then simply copy the value from column3 into column2 and clear column3's value using `ClearContents`:

```
Sub Concat()

    'Loop through all the rows
    For Each Row In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows

    'Look at the cell in the first column of the current row
    'If value is "London" concatinate column 1 and 2 and store in column1
    'Note, the check for "London" is an exact, case sensative check!

        If Row.Columns(1) = "London" Then
            Row.Columns(1) = Row.Columns(1) & " " & Row.Columns(2)
            Row.Columns(2) = Row.Columns(3)
            Row.Columns(3).ClearContents
        End If
    Next Row
End Sub
```